# Huawei power saver app allowing app to run in background

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I've developed an app which `receives push notifications from Parse`. The app is designed to run in background so that notifications can be received even when app is closed.

But we are facing challenge with `Huawei's` devices due to its custom "power savings" feature which detects the app as power intensive and hence clears it from memory when screen is locked.

Are there any known methods to prevent the app from being restricted or to add it to "Protected Apps" list upon installation?

Note: We begun with `GCM` notificatoins, but after learning that `GCM's` notification deliverability is flaky, we moved on to `Parse.com's PPNS` and then this new roadblock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cant do much except detect the device,if device is huawei warn the user about propably issue if the desired app wont be added to protected apps hence this is the only way to do what we need.No other ways available and i reckon it will never be!